# Spinner List show when press spinner but list item does not select and not showing in Toast

Tags: android

This is my code i am very tried to show item in spinner  but all is vain
list show when press spinner arrow but does not select and does not show in toast so please help me and guide me where I am wrong

```
 public class MakeComplain extends AppCompatActivity implements    
 OnItemSelectedListener {
 private Spinner spinner,spinner1,spinner3;
 private TextView txtCategory;

 private ArrayList<String> Station;



private JSONArray result;


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_make_complain);
    Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

     spinner1 = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.station);
    spinner3 = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.generator);
    spinner = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.complain);

    spinner1.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
            //Get data from the list which you had set to the adapter of spinner1
            Toast.makeText(MakeComplain.this, "Spinner1 Item Clicked: "+position, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }

        @Override
        public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {

        }
    });

    spinner3.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
            //Get data from the list which you had set to the adapter of spinner3
            Toast.makeText(MakeComplain.this, "Spinner3 Item Clicked: "+position, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }

        @Override
        public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {

        }
    });

    ArrayAdapter arrayAdapter = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(this, R.array.Complain, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item);
    spinner.setAdapter(arrayAdapter);


    spinner1.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, this.fetchTwitterPublicTimeline()));
    spinner3.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, this.fetchGeneratorList()));





}
public ArrayList<String> fetchTwitterPublicTimeline()
{
    final  ArrayList<String> listItems = new ArrayList<String>();

    new Thread(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            try {
                URL url = new URL("http://bigbi.com/cs/Station.php");
                HttpURLConnection urlConnection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
                urlConnection.setRequestMethod("GET");
                //urlConnection.setRequestProperty("User-Agent", "Mozilla/5.0");
                InputStream stream = urlConnection.getInputStream();
                InputStreamReader reader = new InputStreamReader(stream);
                BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(reader);
                String line;
                while ((line = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null) {
                    JSONArray ja = new JSONArray(line);

                    for (int i = 0; i < ja.length(); i++) {
                        JSONObject jo = (JSONObject) ja.get(i);
                        listItems.add(jo.getString("name"));
                    }
                }
                bufferedReader.close();
            } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }).start();

    return listItems;
}
public ArrayList<String> fetchGeneratorList()
{
    final  ArrayList<String> listItems = new ArrayList<String>();

    new Thread(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            try {
                URL url = new URL("http://biges.com/12/get.php");
                HttpURLConnection urlConnection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
                urlConnection.setRequestMethod("GET");
                //urlConnection.setRequestProperty("User-Agent", "Mozilla/5.0");
                InputStream stream = urlConnection.getInputStream();
                InputStreamReader reader = new InputStreamReader(stream);
                BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(reader);
                String line;
                while ((line = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null) {
                    JSONArray ja = new JSONArray(line);

                    for (int i = 0; i < ja.length(); i++) {
                        JSONObject jo = (JSONObject) ja.get(i);
                        listItems.add(jo.getString("gen_no"));
                    }
                }
                bufferedReader.close();
            } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }).start();

    return listItems;
}
public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position,
                           long id) {


}


@Override
public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0) {
}
```

}

Comment: after that same result not showing

Answer (score 0):

Please try with this,

```
spinner1.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, R.layout.spinner_item, fetchTwitterPublicTimeline()));
spinner3.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, R.layout.spinner_item,fetchGeneratorList()));
```

for clicking on item can add.

```
public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position,
                           long id) {

Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Item clicked",
   Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();


}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have missed two things.

1. You haven't added the listener for selecting an item. Add the following to add the listener.

   ```
   spinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(this);
   ```

   Add the same for other spinners if you want.
2. Add the code for showing toast in `onItemSelected()` method. Something like this

   ```
   Toast.makeText(this, "Item Clicked", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
   ```

Answer (score 0):

You had implemented listener for onItemSelection for spinner but you didn't set the onItemSelection to the spinner, so update your onCreate like this:

```
@Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_make_complain);
        Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

        spinner1 = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.station);
        spinner3 = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.generator);
        spinner = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.complain);

        spinner1.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
                //Get data from the list which you had set to the adapter of spinner1
                Toast.makeText(this, "Spinner1 Item Clicked: "+position, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }

            @Override
            public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {

            }
        });

        spinner3.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
                //Get data from the list which you had set to the adapter of spinner3
                Toast.makeText(this, "Spinner3 Item Clicked: "+position, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }

            @Override
            public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {

            }
        });

        spinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
                //Get data from the list which you had set to the adapter of spinner
                Toast.makeText(this, "Spinner Item Clicked: "+position, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }

            @Override
            public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {

            }
        });

        ArrayAdapter arrayAdapter = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(this, R.array.Complain, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item);
        spinner.setAdapter(arrayAdapter);

        Station=this.fetchTwitterPublicTimeline();

        spinner1.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, R.layout.spinner_item,R.id.txt, this.fetchTwitterPublicTimeline()));
        spinner3.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, R.layout.spinner_item,R.id.txt, this.fetchGeneratorList()));

    }
```

Individually I set here setOnItemSelectedListener to spinners because if we override one method as you are doing then you will not able to find out which spinners item selection is callback.

So for this remove the implementation for implements
 OnItemSelectedListener from your Activity and relatively it's overrided methods also and do as I answered.

Comment: I tired same as you but problem still

Comment: If you are doing like this then what is happening

Comment: Remove implements OnItemSelectedListener from activity

Comment: after remove implements problem is same